# Error on Media CSS tag | at-rule or selector expected

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I'm getting some of the fuzzy red lines under this css, I've looked around and can't seem to solve this one.

I've followed W3 school saying to put the body {} around the padding-left but that didn't work.

What needs to be done here?

Please help, is this just a VSCode thing?

[image]

Edit: Thanks to those who got involved, keep in mind i didn't write any of that, also CSS and I aren't friends.

Comment: The selectors go inside the [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), your media queries seem to be combined with your selectors. `@media (query) { .selector { styleProperty: value; } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've applied the media queries incorrectly. Please refer https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp to check the correct syntax for media queries.

The selector must be inside the rule. Your selector is outside the rule and the syntax is plain wrong.

In your case, it would be:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1200px){
    .login_right_content{
        padding-left:80px;
    }
}
```

You can use the above structure for your other media queries as well.